# Reverse engineering of data structure

Tags: .net, hex, blob, reverse-engineering, data-conversion

I'm doing reverse engineering of an .net application which store in the DB (Firebird) following blob. It contains 18 numbers between ~0.00 and ~6.00. Do you know what data structure this could be and how to reverse this hex to decimal or float which are in this range 0.00~6.00.

```
FE 13 73 64 7A 59 FB 3F EB 8C 9B 85 26 75 05 40 A0 2F 2D 06 96 73 00 40 B8
A8 BE 1D 0F E5 01 40 D2 DF C9 6A 79 83 03 40 97 65 59 96 65 B9 0C 40 B2 88
F1 7E 55 DE 05 40 E4 45 5E E4 45 9E 00 40 34 05 20 CD 9E B9 FB 3F 58 20 9F
8B 53 D2 FC 3F 1A 44 DB 4D 77 4E 02 40 03 F9 5C 9C 92 B6 FF 3F 85 54 48 85 
54 C8 00 40 E0 C9 6A 79 63 04 05 40 87 05 F2 B9 38 25 09 40 2D 41 79 FA 0D 
66 03 40 CA 77 49 64 11 A3 FE 3F 57 AA D8 BD 10 7F FD 3F
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the numbers are just 18 IEEE-754 double precision floats concatenated together.

You can use [`BitConverter.ToDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert 8 of these bytes to a number again. So you would have to iterate over this array of bytes, in chunks of 8 bytes.

Your particular example would result in the following numbers:

```
FE 13 73 64 7A 59 FB 3F => 1.7093452380952
EB 8C 9B 85 26 75 05 40 => 2.6822023809524
A0 2F 2D 06 96 73 00 40 => 2.0564384920635
B8 A8 BE 1D 0F E5 01 40 => 2.2368452380952
D2 DF C9 6A 79 83 03 40 => 2.4391964285714
97 65 59 96 65 B9 0C 40 => 3.5905257936508
B2 88 F1 7E 55 DE 05 40 => 2.7335615079365
E4 45 5E E4 45 9E 00 40 => 2.0772817460317
34 05 20 CD 9E B9 FB 3F => 1.7328174603175
58 20 9F 8B 53 D2 FC 3F => 1.8013492063492
1A 44 DB 4D 77 4E 02 40 => 2.2883134920635
03 F9 5C 9C 92 B6 FF 3F => 1.9820734126984
85 54 48 85 54 C8 00 40 => 2.0978174603175
E0 C9 6A 79 63 04 05 40 => 2.6271428571429
87 05 F2 B9 38 25 09 40 => 3.1431746031746
2D 41 79 FA 0D 66 03 40 => 2.4248313492063
CA 77 49 64 11 A3 FE 3F => 1.9148115079365
57 AA D8 BD 10 7F FD 3F => 1.8435218253968
```